# jQuery ajax response shows in browser instead of being passed to the callback function

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery

I have a web application that logs into another web service and may perform some actions for a user.

I'm using codeigniter and jQuery. I have set up a controller in codeigniter specifically for handling ajax requests. The controller does whatever it needs to and then `echo`s json.

The ajax call below is supposed to take the username and password for the other web service and post them to my ajax controller. The controller uses the values to attempt to log into the other service (using curl). The json response reflects whether the login was successful or not.

My problem is that sometimes my browser is redirected to the ajax controller, so the json response is `echo`ed to the browser. I can't pinpoint why or when this is happening. When it happens, the `success` function is not called.

```
/* Verify login credentials
 *
 * @param username, password
 * @param activityElement - element in which to place activity indicator
 * @param location - location to refresh after success
 * @return none
*/
function verify_login(username, password, activityElement, location) 
{  
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?=site_url('ajax/eval_login')?>',
        data: { username: username, password: password },
    beforeSend:function() {
        window.savedHtml = $(activityElement).html();
        $(activityElement).html('<div id="activity"></div><div class="text-center">Verifying </div>');
        $('#activity').activity(); //neteye activity indicator plugin
    },
    success:function(data) {
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
        if (data.success) {
            $(activityElement).html(window.savedHtml);

            //fades in success message then performs function
            set_message('Success!',function() {
                alert(location);
                window.location.href = "<?=site_url()?>/" + location;
            });
        } else {
            $(activityElement).html(window.savedHtml);
            set_message(data.error);
        }    
        $('#activity').activity(false);
        set_clicks();
    },
    error:function(){
        set_message('<strong>Oops!</strong> Try that again in a few moments.</p>');
        $('#activity').activity(false);
        $(activityElement).html(window.savedHtml);
    }
    });
}
```

Edit:
I'm pretty confused. I doesn't really seem like the ajax request is the issue... makes no sense to me

walking through it again..

1. request is sent with the `.ajax` call
2. sometimes everything works as expected (request comes back, ui is updated)
3. sometimes the browser just goes to `http://yadayada.local/index.php/ajax/eval_login` where the proper json response is displayed (see screenshot below..). It's interesting that the proper json response is being displayed. If the browser were simply redirected there would be no output since `$_POST` would be empty...

[image: screenshot]

Comment: By the way `beforeSend` callback is not meant for messing with UI, but for accessing the raw request headers before sending - just put that lines after the ajax call.

Comment: Install the HTTP Headers plugin for FF and leave it "always on top". You'll be able to record all requests and responses. With some luck you'll figure out where the issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I had pointed the form action to the ajax controller for some reason and `event.preventDefault()` was only working sometimes. Can't believe I did that.. I guess I deserved it for sloppy logic

Comment: If this solved your problem then you should accept it as your answer in order to help others that may find this post.

Comment: @Miguel-F SO won't let me accept my own answer for 23 more hours :)

Comment: Thank you , saved my life ahahah

Answer (score 1):

I would use your browsers network inspector to look at the response on one of the failed requests, this may shed some light on an issue within your applications response.

@see http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events
"This event is only called if the request was successful (no errors from the server, no errors with the data)."

So it's either the response code or the response data causing this to fail.

Comment: Hey lotsofcode. Firebug isn't giving me much to work with, just an error that says "The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared." which makes sense since its just json. It isn't even displaying the post details though

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need this line:

```
data = $.parseJSON(data);
```

Try to run it without it.